# How to show double and integers in a TableView in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a table with 5 rows and 5 columns. I am trying to insert double numbers and integer numbers. On column 1 and 2 (double numbers) and column 3 and 4 (integer) and last column images.
I am trying to figure out what the error is in the code I wrote:

```
#ifndef ITEMROI_H
#define ITEMROI_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class itemRoi
{
public:
    itemRoi(int &size, const QString &threeDLocation, const QString &concavity,
            int &color, const QByteArray &imagesData = QByteArray());

    int size() const { return mSize; }
    QString threeDLocation() const { return m3DLocation; }
    QString concavity() const { return mConcavity; }
    int color() const { return mColor; }
    QByteArray imagesData() const { return mImagesData; }

private:
    int mSize;
    double m3DLocation;
    double mConcavity;
    int mColor;
    QByteArray mImagesData;
};
#endif // ITEMROI_H
```

I am getting errors on the following parts:

```
QString threeDLocation() const { return m3DLocation; }
QString concavity() const { return mConcavity; }
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? What model are you using? Where are you using itemRoi?

Comment: Change `QString threeDLocation() const { return m3DLocation; }` to `QString threeDLocation() const { return QString::number(m3DLocation); }` See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6

Comment: With that said you probably don't need to mention `QTableView` since it is unclear how that is even part of the question. I mean the code has no `QTableView`.

Comment: "I am getting errors on the following parts:" - *What* errors? Why would you think posting the actual error message was not relevant? Also; please always post code in [mcve] form. That enables us to help you better and creating the MCVE helps *you* find your bug.

Comment: Thanks Eyllanesc! Problem solved by adding what you were suggesting! QString threeDLocation() const { return QString::number(m3DLocation); }

Comment: @Emanuele Do not change the title to SOLVED, you must publish an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks Eyllanesc. I would like to mark it as correct but the "V" symbol does not appear. Let me know.